# Status code of HTTP response of server in Android phone is printed in the body of response

Tags: android, httpresponse

I am using http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/examples/org/apache/http/examples/ElementalHttpServer.java  for Android.

I set the response using the following code:

```
HttpResponse getResponse = new BasicHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, 404, "Not Found");
getResponse.setEntity(new StringEntity(new String("The requested resource " + target + " could not be found due to mismatch!!")));  
conn.sendResponseHeader(getResponse);
conn.sendResponseEntity(getResponse);
```

My response in Mozilla Poster or browser has the header 404 and the response body as:

```
The requested resource  could not be found due to mismatch!!HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

How can I get only the HTTP body String? Why am I getting HTTP/1.1 200 OK in response. I dont set this in my code. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a link to Apache CORE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a problem in my defined handle() method. I was creating a new HttpResponse for each request instead of using the response passed in the

```
public void handle(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help you...
 i think `response`  is what you need

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse httpResponse;

        try {
            httpResponse = client.execute(request);
            responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {

                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                response = convertStreamToString(instream);

                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                instream.close();
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I want to remove the response headers and print only the HTTP body in the browser. @ashish.n

Comment: headers = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FirstName", "myName"));
you can send blank header here instead of myName you can send a blank value...